# Setting filetype in vim file does not result in correct syntax highlighting

Tags: vim

I am using [xolox/vim-notes](https://github.com/xolox/vim-notes) and want to be able to use the notes syntax highlighting with notes that reside outside of the designated notes directory. My understanding is that one should be able to `set ft=notes` to enable the correct syntax highlighting. However, this does not work.

I have tried posting a question on the github page but the developer has not answered. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: Yes, wait for xolox to answer your question.

Comment: You are right but the developer hadn't seemed to answer many recent questions so I thought I would ask here as it was more of a general question regarding syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I am using vim-plug as my plugin manager and I had the following in my vimrc:
`Plug 'xolox/vim-notes',{'on':[ 'Note' ,'SearchNotes']} | Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'`

When I set ft=notes the plugin was not invoked. I just needed to remove 
`,{'on':[ 'Note' ,'SearchNotes']} | Plug 'xolox/vim-misc'`